# rpy2: represent NA in Python as an argument to R function

Tags: python, r, rpy2, lme4

I'm trying to pass an `NA` to R function, e.g., make predictions with a `lme4` mixed model using only fixed effects (i.e., without random effects):

```
import rpy2.rinterface as ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
rstats = importr('stats')
rstats.predict( mymodel, re_form=ri.NA_Logical )
```

However, `re_form=ri.NA_Logical` fails to pass `NA` to `re.form` (I've tried also aliases `REform`, `ReForm`, etc.), for some reason. Any ideas?

This R function: 
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lme4/versions/1.1-20/topics/predict.merMod

Answer (score 2):

This might be an issue with function dispatch / ellipsis in the signature of the generic (if an ellipsis is used in the signature of the generic rpy2 has no way to know that it should translate `.` to `_` for a yet-unknown named argument).

Try:

```
rstats.predict(mymodel, **{'re.form': ri.NA_Logical})
```

or:

```
lme4 = importr('lme4')
lme4.predict_merMod(mymodel, re_form=ri.NA_Logical)
```

Relevant sections in the doc are https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/robjects_rpackages.html#importing-r-packages and https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/robjects_functions.html#rpy2.robjects.functions.SignatureTranslatedFunction (the latter mostly means that the doc is the code).

**edit:**

It is also possible to mix R code with Python a creative way. For example:

```
myfunc = robjects.r('function (x) predict.merMod(x, re.form=NA)')
myfunc(mymodel)
```

Comment: I've tried both suggestions and a combination of them. Unfortunately, the value of the argument is still not passed to the function.

Comment: Can I somehow check what arguments this function accepts (from Python)?

Comment: What is "this function" here ? Remember that you are calling R functions from Python. The R generic `predict()` has an ellipsis argument, and rpy2 makes that R function callable from Python accept all and any arguments. If you could provide a self-contained example and show how it differs from R it would help show us the exact problem.